# Сколько дней прошло с момента регистрации

Tags: php

Как узнать сколько дней прошло с момента регистрации? Мне почему-то кажется, что мой вариант кривой:

```
echo (abs(time() - $reg_time)) / 86400;
```

Comment: @ua6xh, нужен пример с timestamp.

Comment: @ModaL ну, вы же программист! Где исследовательский подход к решению проблемы? [`DateTime::setTimestamp()`][1]

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.settimestamp.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP еще в версии 5.3 появилась очень мощная поддержка времени/дат

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($reg_time);
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff($date, true);
$days = $diff->d;
```

Как видите, я даже не уверен, вернет ли дифф по умолчанию положительный результат. Потому что мне это не нужно, и я могу переложить этот геморрой на SPL.

Comment: @Etki, мало того, что ошибка в коде из-за , true), так ещё и вообще число 13 отдало. С потолка походу.

Comment: @ModaL, код поправил, с потолка он ничего не берет. Возмонжо, надо подкрутить таймзону, но по идее здесь у них одна и та же должна быть.

Comment: @Etki, не знаю, но показывает число 13. С момента моей регистрации прошло около 35 дней.

Answer (score 1):

Прошу проследовать в мануал → [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-diff.php)

Более удачный [пример](http://date-php.ru/date_diff) работы.